# Unresolved external symbol when using static

Tags: c++

I am new to c++. I started now playing with classes and I am having a noob problem with statics.

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(){};
    ~Test(){};
    static void test();
    static Helper* helper;
};

void Test::test()
{
    Object obj = Test::helper->getObject();
    //...
}
```

When I try to compile it gives the error:

```
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class Helper* Test::helper" (?helper@Test@@2PAVHelper@@A)
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: The linker complains because it can't find an instance of your static `Helper` member. Every static class member must be uniquely defined in global scope (i.e. oustide any class/struct definition) so you must provide a definition for `Helper` just like you did for `test`. Granted, linker error messages are not the most user-friendly in the world, but just wait until you face your first template instanciation error :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define Test::helper. Write something like this outside the class:

```
Helper* Test::helper = new Helper;
```

Answer (score 2):

The first answer is correct.  The reason behind this is that you need to allocate memory for static objects outside the class definition.  If you define the the class in a header file, and include it in several cpp files, the compiler doesn't know where and how you want to create the object that 'helper' points to.